# Как удалить символ, который повторяется более N раз?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

К примеру есть строка "**111111333322**" , и N=3. Так вот, вернуть должно **11133322**, то есть, я удалил все повторяющиеся элементы после N и оставил кол-во символов равное N.

Такое вообще решить можно с помощью регулярного выражения или нет?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var n = 3;
var rex = new RegExp("((.)\\2{" + (n-1) + "})\\2+", 'g');

console.log("111111333322".replace(rex, "$1"));
```

Для двухзначных чисел через пробел:

```js
var n = 3;
var rex = new RegExp("(\\b(\\d+)(?: \\2){" + (n-1) + "})(?: \\2)+\\b", 'g');

console.log("23 23 23 23 26 26".replace(rex, "$1"));
console.log("23 23 23 230".replace(rex, "$1"));
console.log("2 2 2 2 2 230 30 30 30 30 30 0 0 0".replace(rex, "$1"));
console.log("2 2 2 2 2".replace(rex, "$1"));
```

Comment: Спасибо.. После твоего кода понимаю что и за год не выучить мне регулярки )

Comment: Тут, наверное, стоит показать, как будет выглядеть литерал регулярного выражения для фиксированного n. Например, для n=8: `/((.)\2{7})\2+/g`

Comment: @Tom, регулярки довольно легко учатся за день. Берёшь https://alf.nu/RegexGolf и сам пытаешься решить всё, что там есть. При этом можно пользоваться википедией и гуглить какие-нибудь конкретные моменты (типа отрицательного предпросмотра), но не решения конкретных задач. Довольно быстро понимаешь, что и как использовать. По крайней мере, в рамках js-синтаксиса, который (пока) несколько ограничен по сравнению с другими языками.

Comment: @mymedia, первая группа используется в замене совпадения на `$1` ;)

Comment: @Tom, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Кстати, а как быть если числа к примеру двоичные?) типо "23 23 23 23 26 26" ?

Comment: @Tom, дополнил ответ. Вроде структура узначаемая, но добавилось несколько `\b` для проверки границ чисел.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Буду потом рассматривать детальнее что тут происходит )
P.S. Оказалось что задачу не решить с помощью регулярки.. Все зря :(

Comment: @Tom, почему не решить?

Comment: Ну оказывается повторения могут идти не подряд) 
Например дается массив [23, 23, 65, 64, 34, 23, 53, 53, 23, 23] вот и нужно удалить повторяющиеся элементы больше N.. 
И выходит что-то вроде этого [23, 23, 65, 64...23] . А это уже надо другой код писать) Я думал они по порядку идут..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66959/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-tom).